# How Was This Made ( WordBall, Clear Tetrahedron)

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

Is anyone familiar with the tools that were used to create the Wordball here | https://jacekjeznach.com/skills/ | and the floating clear Tetrahedron with images here | https://jacekjeznach.com/about/ | ? Any advice at all would be extremely appreciated.

I tried to recreate both of these using THREEjs however I was not successful. I could not implement the mouse follow for the wordball (or the word ball in general) or the clear background and images for the tetrahedron

Comment: You could just email the author and ask...

Comment: I tried to about a month ago and no luck. Good advice though.

Comment: It seems it was made using the element `canvas` and a 2D context. For reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very simple indeed.
but first you have to attach javascript library called cloudTag.js.
[CloudTag Can Be Download From Here](https://www.jqueryscript.net/text/Minimal-jQuery-Based-3D-Ball-Tag-Cloud-cloudTag-js.html)

Then Add Jquery CDN

```
*<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>*
```

Add HTML

```
<div id="tagcloud">

<ul>

<li><a href="#">Tag 1</a></li>

<li><a href="#">Tag 2</a></li>

<li><a href="#">Tag 3</a></li>

...

</ul>

</div>
```

Add Javascript.

```
var settings = {
//height of sphere container
height: 400,
//width of sphere container
width: 400,
//radius of sphere
radius: 150,
//rotation speed
speed: 3,
//sphere rotations slower
slower: 0.9,
//delay between up<a href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/">date</a> position
timer: 5,
//dependence of a font size on axis Z
fontMultiplier: 15,
//tag css stylies on mouse over
hoverStyle: {
border: 'none',
color: '#0b2e6f'
},
//tag css stylies on mouse out
mouseOutStyle: {
border: '',
color: ''
}
};

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#tagcloud').tagoSphere(settings);
});
```

Comment: But it is a very basic design. You need to add more complex CSS to modify it.

Comment: You know your stuff man. Thank you so much! Do you have an idea regarding the floating (not cursor responsive) Tetrahedron?

Comment: Use cloudTag.js...[Download it from here](https://www.jqueryscript.net/text/Minimal-jQuery-Based-3D-Ball-Tag-Cloud-cloudTag-js.html)...............Connect cloudTag.js and jquery the copy above code as it is.